# Scale down image to fit in intent

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-intent, scale

I have to send a bitmap in an intent as intent-extra. The problem is, that the maximum data size of an intent is 50KB. How can I scale down the bitmap to fit into the intent?

AFAIK the camera app does the same to put image previews into the result intent of `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Where does the image come from? Maybe you can put its ID instead of the image itself?

Comment: The Problem is, that the taget activity only handles bitmap-objects of the intent extra.

Answer (score 0):

use scaled bitmap method of bitmap to specifying size of your scaled down/up image.

Comment: How do I specify the data-size of the resulting image?

Answer (score 0):

The `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` method has parameters for the desired target height en width.
Have you tried this?

Comment: The problem is, that I don't know the target height and width but only the target image size in bytes.

Comment: I see. In that case I think you will have no choice but to do it in a loop, reducing the height and width until the result is < 50K big. The only way I know to get the resulting filesize is by using bitmap.compress() to a FileOutputStream, and getting the length() of the File.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (photoBitmap, dest_width, dest_height, false);
```